# What is wrong with the bs4 documentation? I can't run unwrap() sample code

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scraperwiki

I'm trying to strip out some fussy text from pages like [this](http://www.bicyclepaintings.com/studio10/johnny/studioindex.html). I want to preserve the anchored links but lose the breaks and the a.intro. I thought I could use something like [unwrap()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) to strip off layers but I'm getting an error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

For kicks, I tried running the documentation sample code itself, since I couldn't see how my version differed.

```
markup = '<a href="http://example.com/">I linked to <i>example.com</i></a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup)
a_tag = soup.a

a_tag.i.unwrap()
a_tag
# <a href="http://example.com/">I linked to example.com</a>
```

I'm getting the exact same error. What am I missing here? I'm working in Scraperwiki, fwiw.

Comment: It seems like a Scraperwiki issue. The `unwrap` example works when run from IPython for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a scraperwiki issue. Works fine in ipython console.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error too.

```
In [27]: type(a_tag.i.unwrap)
Out[27]: NoneType

In [28]: 'unwrap' in dir(a_tag.i)
Out[28]: False
```

FWIW, `replace_with_children` yields the same results:

```
In [29]: type(a_tag.i.replace_with_children)
Out[29]: NoneType
```

Looks like a bug to me.

```
In [13]: import BeautifulSoup as Bs

In [16]: Bs.__version__
Out[16]: '3.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message with `soup.select()`. The reason was an old version of the BeautifulSoup4 library. Somebody at ScraperWiki fixed it (see [this conversation](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/scraperwiki/SJqDr-Jg1MA) at the ScraperWiki Google Group).